# Can someone point out the problem in my linked list implementation?

Tags: c++, linked-list

When I compile the following code, I get compile error that " head does not name a type".
Can someone explain what goes wrong ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
/* Link list node */
struct node {
    int val;
    struct node* next;
    node(int x)
    {
        this->val = x;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

    struct node *head =  new node(3);
    head -> next = new node(4);   // error: head does not name a type.
    head -> next->next = new node(5);  // error: head does not name a type.
 
 void print(){
   struct node* temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << temp->val << " ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    

int main()
{
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

I cannot figure out why am i getting the error . Please someone help me out .

Comment: Put the offending code into `main`.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use `struct` keyword when declaring new `node` instances.

Comment: @David G Can you please explain why ?

Comment: C++ doesn't allow general statements outside of functions. Only declarations and definitions may be outside functions. This should really have been explained by any decent book, tutorial or class.

Comment: C++ does not require the use of the keyword `struct` when referring to a a struct type name, but it does no harm to use it. As a general word of advice when dealing with linked list structures, make sure to use a paper and pencil to _draw_ what you want to happen, and in what order it needs to be done, all before you try to write code that does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only declarations are allowed outside of functions. Expressions such as `head->next = node(4)` need to be inside a function. You should move that code into `main()`.